# Firebase Data with Eureka & Init

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, initialization, eureka-forms

I'm confused on how to properly save data to firebase with Eureka, using init. Resources I have checked out don't seem to clarify my answer. Not sure the best way to do this.

I have a file called `User.swift` that contains a struct:

```
`struct UsersInfo {

let email: String
let password: String
let first: String
let last: String
let about: String
let age: Int
let city: String
let firebaseReference: DatabaseReference?

init(email: String, password: String, first: String, last: String, about: String, age: Int, city: String) {
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.about = about
    self.age = age
    self.city = city
    self.firebaseReference = nil
}

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
    self.email = snapshotValue["email"] as! String
    self.password = snapshotValue["password"] as! String
    self.first = snapshotValue["first"] as! String
    self.last = snapshotValue["last"] as! String
    self.age = snapshotValue["age"] as! Int
    self.city = snapshotValue["city"] as! String
    self.about = snapshotValue["about"] as! String
    self.firebaseReference = snapshot.ref
}
} // End Struct.
```

Then I have a file/view controller that imports Eureka using `FormViewController`. My Eureka rows that are set to values, are located in this file as followed:

```
    // Get the value of a single row
    let emailrow: EmailRow? = form.rowBy(tag: "emailRowTag")
    let emailvalue = emailrow?.value
    // Get the value of a single row
    let passwordrow: PasswordRow? = form.rowBy(tag: "passwordRowTag")
    let passwordvalue = passwordrow?.value
    // Get the value of a single row
    let firstrow: NameRow? = form.rowBy(tag: "firstRowTag")
    let firstvalue = firstrow?.value
    // Get the value of a single row
    let lastrow: TextRow? = form.rowBy(tag: "lastRowTag")
    let lastvalue = lastrow?.value
    // Get the value of a single row
    let aboutrow: TextRow? = form.rowBy(tag: "aboutRowTag")
    let aboutvalue = aboutrow?.value
    // Get the value of a single row
    let agerow: IntRow? = form.rowBy(tag: "ageRowTag")
    let agevalue = agerow?.value
    // Get the value of a single row
    let cityrow: PushRow<String>? = form.rowBy(tag: "cityRowTag")
    let cityvalue = cityrow?.value
```

In this file/view controller, I have a custom button using ButtonRow from Eureka. I implemented a function to do this and called it `onCellSelection`. The values of rows is what confusing me with Firebase and what I need to put in my snapshotValue dictionary in the `User.swift` file and to execute in `FormViewController`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I did was give the row of type TextRow a tag

so I had something like

```
row.tag = "username"
```

Then after that I was able to retrieve that tag with the following code

```
let usernameRow: TextRow? = form.rowBy(tag: "username")

let username: String? = usernameRow?.cell.textField.text
```

Firebase only allows strings to push to the database so now that you have that, you can call the `setValue` function and pass the variable username

```
firebaseref.setValue("username": username)
```